# Scrapy stops scraping but continues to crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I’m trying to scrape different information from several pages of a website.
Until the sixteenth page, everything works: the pages are crawled, scraped and the information stock in my database, however after the sixteenth page, it stops scraping but continues to crawl.
I checked the website and there are more of 470 pages with information. The HTML tags are the same, so I don't understand why it stopped scraping.

Python:

```
def url_lister():
    url_list = []
    page_count = 1
    while page_count < 480:
        url = 'https://www.active.com/running?page=%s' %page_count 
        url_list.append(url)
        page_count += 1 
    return url_list

class ListeCourse_level1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ListeCAP_ACTIVE' 
    allowed_domains = ['www.active.com'] 
    start_urls = url_lister()
    
    def parse(self, response):    
        selector = Selector(response)
        for uneCourse in response.xpath('//*[@id="lpf-tabs2-a"]/article/div/div/div/a[@itemprop="url"]'): 
            loader = ItemLoader(ActiveItem(), selector=uneCourse)
            loader.add_xpath('nom_evenement', './/div[2]/div/h5[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
        loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(string) 
        loader.default_output_processor = Join()
        yield loader.load_item()
    pass
```

The shell:

```
>     2018-01-23 17:22:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200     
>     https://www.active.com/running?page=15>
>     {
>      'nom_evenement': 'Enniscrone 10k run & 5k run/walk',
>      }
>     2018-01-23 17:22:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.active.com/running?page=16> (referer: None)
>     --------------------------------------------------
>                     SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
>     --------------------------------------------------
>     2018-01-23 17:22:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 17 pages (at 17 pages/min), scraped 155 items (at 155 items/min)
>     2018-01-23 17:22:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.active.com/running?page=17> (referer: None)
> 
> --------------------------------------------------
>                 SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
> -------------------------------------------------- 2018-01-23 17:22:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.active.com/running?page=18> (referer: None)
> --------------------------------------------------
>                 SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
> -------------------------------------------------- 2018-01-23 17:22:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.active.com/running?page=19> (referer: None)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you wait for Scrapy to finish crawling?

Comment: Yes I wait each time

Comment: I have a spider that is currently running and has crawled 15783 pages, but only scraped 625. It scrapes the links for the first few URLs that I have supplied in `start_urls` (out of a long list of values), but then stops scraping. I haven't been able to find documentation that would explain this behavior.

Comment: It seems the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by the fact that there are only 17 pages with the content you are looking for, while you instruct Scrapy to visit all 480 pages of form `https://www.active.com/running?page=NNN`. A better approach is to check on each page you visit that there is a next page and only in that case yield `Request` to the next page.

So, I would refactor your code to something like (not tested):

```
class ListeCourse_level1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ListeCAP_ACTIVE' 
    allowed_domains = ['www.active.com'] 
    base_url = 'https://www.active.com/running'
    start_urls = [base_url]

    def parse(self, response):    
        selector = Selector(response)
        for uneCourse in response.xpath('//*[@id="lpf-tabs2-a"]/article/div/div/div/a[@itemprop="url"]'): 
            loader = ItemLoader(ActiveItem(), selector=uneCourse)
            loader.add_xpath('nom_evenement', './/div[2]/div/h5[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
        loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(string) 
        loader.default_output_processor = Join()
        yield loader.load_item()
        # check for next page link
        if response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "next-page")]'):
            next_page = response.meta.get('page_number', 1) + 1
            next_page_url = '{}?page={}'.format(base_url, next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': next_page})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your proposal, unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I tried to scrap the 'tbody' tag in the scrapy shell, and I realised that it returns an empty answer. I do not understand why because the text is present in the code and there is not AJAX method or stuff like that, which can bug the script... To be continued !

Comment: JavaScript often changes the source code too. I encounter this quite often in particular with `table`s - in developer tools I can see `tbody` present but it's missing in the page source. Anyway, do you actually need to look for `tbody` tag? I don't recall all the details, but it's nowhere in the code sample.

Comment: Oh excuse-me it's because I changed of website to test it in an another source. I open a new discussion to put the new code, ok ? I will call it 'Scrapy tbody tag return an ampty answer but has text inside' !